# Passing a model value through a popover in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to use a Bootstrap popover (from Angular-Bootstrap) to modify a model value on the `$scope` of a controller.  It seems that the popover template is breaking some connection.

I made a small example to show my issue:

Directive 1 (`master-directive`) takes in the model as an isolate scope property.  It's template is a button that displays a popover.  The template for the popover shows directive 2 (`sub-directive`) which is fed the model value through an isolate scope property, and would contain some sort of UI control to modify that property (in the demo, this is just a mouse click).

Normally the changes would propagate back up to the controller (`sub-directive` model is two-way bound to the `master-directive` model which is then two-way bound to the controller model.  However, when the template that contains `sub-directive` is used in the popover, the two-way binding between `sub-directive` and `master-directive` is broken.  Any changes to the model in `sub-directive` will stay local to that directive, and are not propagated upwards.

Relevant Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZnmNUtajXsAHJjCdkkJ?p=preview

Here is the same Plunkr without the popover, demonstrating that it works:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Mr4djvZCVpEUkgDZpyvV?p=preview

Is there a step I am missing to bridge the gaps that are introduced with the popover module?

Comment: Any reason for the downvote...?  Or are you just scanning for no code samples and downvoting whenever you can't see the obvious Plunkr links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store you data in an object, rather than a Javascript primitive (number), the problem is resolved. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IpZbGtMFRyt18BTsoh0c?p=info).

Store your data in an object like this:

```
$scope.data = { num: 5 };
```

Instead of this:

```
$scope.num = 5;
```

My assumption is that the popover is creating a child scope. B/c of the way prototypical inheritance works, the number property in the child scope [shadows the number property in the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/398606) (eg. the parent's value doesn't change when the child's does).